# what is the equivalent of ligo "compile-parameter" for smartpy?

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy, ligo

The Smartpy compiler allow to compile a contract (compiling the code and the initial storage) but I don't see any "compile-parameter" option, that would allow to convert a smartpy command to a michelson representation.

How can I call a deployed smartpy contract ?

ps : I tried to add a compilation target like this:

```
sp.add_expression_compilation_target("minting", FA12(admin=sp.address("tz1cpb3rLapo7RbsZNE3Qy6TMzqNWCxk9hXA"), config  = FA12_config(
                support_upgradable_metadata         = True,
                use_token_metadata_offchain_view    = True
            ),
            token_metadata = {
                "decimals"    : "18",             # Mandatory by the spec
                "name"        : "TestToken", # Recommended
                "symbol"      : "TEST",            # Recommended
                # Extra fields
                "icon"        : 'https://smartpy.io/static/img/logo-only.svg'
            }).mint({"address" : sp.address("tz1cpb3rLapo7RbsZNE3Qy6TMzqNWCxk9hXA"), "value" : 12}))
```

but the compilator give me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "contracts/FA12.py", line 453, in <module>
    sp.add_expression_compilation_target("minting", FA12(admin=sp.address("tz1cpb3rLapo7RbsZNE3Qy6TMzqNWCxk9hXA"), config  = FA12_config(
  File "contracts/FA12.py", line 130, in mint
    sp.set_type(params, sp.TRecord(address = sp.TAddress, value = sp.TNat))
Exception: New command outside of contract (line 130 of contracts/FA12.py):
(set_type (map ("contracts/FA12.py" 130) ((literal (string "address") ("contracts/FA12.py" 130)) (literal (address "tz1cpb3rLapo7RbsZNE3Qy6TMzqNWCxk9hXA") ("contracts/FA12.py" 463))) ((literal (string "value") ("contracts/FA12.py" 130)) (literal (intOrNat 12) ("contracts/FA12.py" 130)))) (record ((address "address") (value "nat")) None) ("contracts/FA12.py" 130))
```

ps2: I tried to add another compilation target like this:

```
    sp.add_expression_compilation_target("minting", mint({"address" : sp.address("tz1cpb3rLapo7RbsZNE3Qy6TMzqNWCxk9hXA"), "value" : 12}))
```

but the compilator give me this error (this is why I have tried to reinit the smart contract in my previous attempt):

```
  File "contracts/FA12.py", line 453, in <module>
    sp.add_expression_compilation_target("minting", mint({"address" : sp.address("tz1cpb3rLapo7RbsZNE3Qy6TMzqNWCxk9hXA"), "value" : 12}))
NameError: name 'mint' is not defined
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

On top of Rodrigo’s answer.

In scenarios, every call generates the corresponding Michelson parameters.

https://smartpy.io/docs/scenarios/testing#registering-and-displaying-calls-to-entry-points

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sp.add_expression_compilation_target("<name>", <expression>)`

https://smartpy.io/docs/compilation_targets#expression-compilation

And then you can compile it with: [~/smartpy-cli/SmartPy.sh compile <...>](https://smartpy.io/docs/cli#smartpysh-compile)

The parameters will be generated inside the `<output-directory>` you provided.

**EDIT:** In the web IDE, you can find the compiled parameters on the output panel.

[image]

Comment: I tried it but there is not a lot of information in the documentation on how to use compilation_target to call a contract functions. I don't know how to use it (I have updated my post with an example of compilation target).

Comment: You are compiling the entire contract in the example you provided, for that you need `sp.add_compilation_target`.

Comment: Yes I tried to only compile the function "mint" but it gives me the following error : ``` name 'mint' is not defined ``` (I have updated my post with an example). This is why I have tried to redefine the contract.

Comment: The entrypoint calls are generated when you run the tests. You can also see them in the right panel on the web IDE after running the tests. https://smartpy.io/ide?cid=QmSNA4hF6viiTsekumqSik6qZ1S4adxSQHFr8LKpjoEo3K&k=1eacd758fd837675bfb4

Comment: Updated the answer with an image

Comment: Ok thanks. Using the web IDE the only way to generate the expression from a function call ?

Comment: No, you can also do it in the CLI. The output will have "_parameter.{tz,json}" files.